# unique breaks error in calculation of quantiles of a data frame in r

Tags: r, dplyr, cut, quantile, quartile

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
       AA        BB        CC       DD

a     name1    59.67      45.9     56.64 

b     name2      0          0       0.3

c     name3    7.14         0      0.55000000000000004
```

I am using dplyr package and I would like to rank each column based on its quartile. 
I am using the following command:

```
df_qnt <- df[2:4] %>% mutate_all(funs(quant = as.integer(cut(as.numeric(.), quantile(as.numeric(.)), include.lowest = TRUE ))))
```

But this error pops up:

```
 Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
 Evaluation error: 'breaks' are not unique.
```

I put quantile function inside unique function. Apparently there is no error but my output does not contain the ranking. Here is the command:

```
 df_qnt <- df[2:4] %>% mutate_all(funs(quant = as.integer(cut(as.numeric(.), unique(quantile(as.numeric(.))), include.lowest = TRUE ))))
```

Anybody can help me with this? 
Thanks

Comment: First, make your `df` available and easily readable (make a reproducible example, use `dput`).  Second, my guess is that you are using `mutate_all` so it tries to make quantiles of your first column  which is `character`, remove it from your  `df` or use `mutate_at`

Comment: Can you include data that makes this more reproducible? Just a vector with enough values to do quantiles would be fine

Answer (score 0):

Actually there was something wrong with Rstudio. My command works perfectly.

Sorry for inconvenience.